# Intubation with bag-mask ventilation after pneumothorax or tension pneumothorax

Tags: unconsciousness, mechanical-ventilation, collapsed-lung, intubation

Why can intubation with vigorous bag-mask ventilation rapidly lead to a further deterioration of an unconscious patient?

Comment: Can you link to the source stating that it can lead to rapid deterioration? That would give us a hint what to look for. Everything can lead to deterioration if not applied properly...

Comment: The source is the ATLS course manual

Comment: Sure sounds like an exam question.

Comment: If you're going to ask a question like this, give the context and what you've learned so far in your attempt to answer the question yourself.  Give citations that can be accessed by readers.  It is a good question, but not properly asked according to Health SE rules.  Edit it a bit.